# Centering the third author in IEEE format?

Tags: ieeetran, ieee-style

How do I put third author in center when using IEEE template?

```
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{First Author}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{Department of System Design Engineering\\
    University of Waterloo, Canada\\
    \textit{\href{mailto:me@example.com}{me@example.com}}%
  }
  \and
  \IEEEauthorblockN{Second Author}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{Department of Electrical, Computer\\ and Software Engineering\\
    University of Ontario Institute of Technology, Canada\\
    \textit{\href{mailto:me@example.com}{me@example.com}}%
  }
  \and
  \IEEEauthorblockN{Third Author}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering\\
    Michigan State University, USA\\
    \textit{\href{mailto:me@example.com}{me@example.com}}%
  }%
}% end author
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by @Mensch, IEEE is a bit strict on the document's layout when using `ieeetran` document class. Therefore, when you have three authors or less you have to place them in line. However, the same issue arises when you have, for instance, five authors.

```
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{2\textsuperscript{nd} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{3\textsuperscript{rd} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{4\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{5\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
}
```

[image: five authors on two lines]

In this specific example, you are allowed to center the two authors placed in the second line. Here is how I do it every time.

**TL;DR:**

At first, define the new command `\linebreakand`.

```
\makeatletter % changes the catcode of @ to 11
\newcommand{\linebreakand}{%
  \end{@IEEEauthorhalign}
  \hfill\mbox{}\par
  \mbox{}\hfill\begin{@IEEEauthorhalign}
}
\makeatother % changes the catcode of @ back to 12
```

Then you can use the new command as a "line-breaker".

```
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{2\textsuperscript{nd} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{3\textsuperscript{rd} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and

\linebreakand % <----- NOTE HERE, breaking after the third one!

\IEEEauthorblockN{4\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{5\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
}
```

[image: five authors centered]

**Brief explanation**

The two macros used as a prologue and epilogue of the command are needed to change the catcode of the '@' char. In that way, you can use it like a regular letter and access protected macro. There is an excellent and comprehensive explanation of the use of `\makeat*` macros [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do).

The command simply closes the `IEEEauthorhalign` macro, inserts some blank space, and then opens the macro again.

Comment: Does not work in case of four authors, split 50-50 over 2 lines. Still off-center, unless the width of the two authors on the top are exactly the same as the two on the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to submit an paper with class `ieeetran` to IEEE, then you should **not**  change the given layout by the class.

IEEE wants you to layout in there class **without** changes to have their well known layout for the book/manual/paper.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it: In the third author add this: \centerline{}

```
\IEEEauthorblockN{Third Author}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{ \centerline{Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering} \\
    Michigan State University, USA\\
    \textit{\href{mailto:me@example.com}{me@example.com}}%
  }%
```